# How to Generate weeks of supply

Tags: teradata

I currently have a table where I have number of units sold and the week that they are sold in. I am trying to get the average of the prior six weeks of units sold. I am using the Fiscal EOW date as the date to show the units sold. I am stumped on this problem.

I am  using the  following:

```
select
b.FISC_EOW_DT,
a.*,
avg(net_unit_qty) over (partition by sid order by FISC_EOW_DT rows between 5 
preceding and current row) as avsaleslast6wk
FROM tbl1 a
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT FISC_WK_OF_MTH_ID,FISC_EOW_DT FROM tbl2 ) B
ON B.FISC_WK_OF_MTH_ID=A.FISC_WK_OF_MTH_ID
where sid = 12345
```

This works however it calculates the last 5 rows, regardless if they are the previous week or not. So for example:

if the weeks was:
12/01/2016
01/08/2017
06/01/2017
08/01/2017

It will calculate the average of these 4 weeks even though they are not consecutive. I need to know how to calculate the Average sales including weeks that are not consecutive. So for the week going back from:

01/08/2017
to
06/01/2017

there would be 0 for average sales since the last 6 weeks are not represented.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
TBL1

SID     FISC_EOW_DT     NET_UNIT_QTY
1234    01/01/2017           1
1234    01/08/2017           2
1234    01/15/2017           3
1234    01/22/2017           2
1234    01/29/2017           1
1234    06/09/2017           1
```

Expected result:

```
SID     FISC_EOW_DT     NET_UNIT_QTY     AVSALESLAST6WEEKS
1234    01/01/2017           1                 0(0+0+0+0+0+0)/6
1234    01/08/2017           2                .167(1+0+0+0+0+0)/6
1234    01/15/2017           3                .50(2+1+0+0+0+0)/6       
1234    01/21/2017           2                 1(3+2+1+0+0+0)/6
1234    01/28/2017           1                 1.33(2+3+2+1+0+0)/6
1234    06/09/2017           1                 0(0+0+0+0+0+0)6<----SINCE THERE HAVE BEEN NO SALES FOR MULTIPLE WEEKS
```

I would like to account for the weeks where there have been no sales. So I will need to create the blank weeks through coding, however I am not sure how to do that.

[image]

```
SELECT 
   D1_PROD_11_SKU_ID
   ,D4_TIME_01_FISC_WK_OF_MTH_ID
  ,FISC_EOW_DT
  ,net_unit_qty
  ,(

   CASE WHEN Min(FISC_EOW_DT) 
              Over (PARTITION BY D1_PROD_11_SKU_ID ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND current row) >= FISC_EOW_DT - 6*7
         THEN Min(net_unit_qty) 
              Over (PARTITION BY D1_PROD_11_SKU_ID ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND current row)
        ELSE 0
    END
+
CASE WHEN Min(FISC_EOW_DT) 
              Over (PARTITION BY D1_PROD_11_SKU_ID ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) >= FISC_EOW_DT -6*7
         THEN Min(net_unit_qty) 
              Over (PARTITION BY D1_PROD_11_SKU_ID ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding)
        ELSE 0
    END
  + CASE WHEN Min(FISC_EOW_DT) 
              Over (PARTITION BY D1_PROD_11_SKU_ID ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 2 Preceding AND 2 Preceding) >= FISC_EOW_DT - 6*7
         THEN Min(net_unit_qty) 
              Over (PARTITION BY D1_PROD_11_SKU_ID ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 2 Preceding AND 2 Preceding)
        ELSE 0
    END
  + CASE WHEN Min(FISC_EOW_DT) 
              Over (PARTITION BY D1_PROD_11_SKU_ID ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 3 Preceding AND 3 Preceding) >= FISC_EOW_DT - 6*7
         THEN Min(net_unit_qty) 
              Over (PARTITION BY D1_PROD_11_SKU_ID ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 3 Preceding AND 3 Preceding)
        ELSE 0
    END
  + CASE WHEN Min(FISC_EOW_DT) 
              Over (PARTITION BY D1_PROD_11_SKU_ID ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 4 Preceding AND 4 Preceding) >= FISC_EOW_DT - 6*7
         THEN Min(net_unit_qty) 
              Over (PARTITION BY D1_PROD_11_SKU_ID ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 4 Preceding AND 4 Preceding)
        ELSE 0
    END
  + CASE WHEN Min(FISC_EOW_DT) 
              Over (PARTITION BY D1_PROD_11_SKU_ID ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 5 Preceding AND 5 Preceding) >= FISC_EOW_DT - 6*7
         THEN Min(net_unit_qty) 
              Over (PARTITION BY D1_PROD_11_SKU_ID ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 5 Preceding AND 5 Preceding)
        ELSE 0
    END


   )  AS ROLLING_SIX_WEEK_SALES
FROM TBL1
```

Comment: Kindly share your sample data and expected result.

Comment: If I am reading the question correctly, the `INNER JOIN` to your fiscal week table (tbl2) does not account for weeks not present in tbl1. Use an `OUTER JOIN` and `ZEROIFNULL()` on the inventory metric to account for weeks not represented.

Comment: I have tried to add the outer join and still get the same result.

Comment: Are you talking about weeks or days? Your `FISC_EOW_DT` seems to be individual days, not the end of a week (which day is supposed to be the end of week?). You can probably create the missing days/weeks using `EXPAND ON` before doing the average.

Comment: I have edited to show weeks. I am using day 7 for the end of week. May not be accurate in the example, but nonetheless I am using day 7 as the end of week. I am not sure how to implement Expand on into this. I will try to research this.

Comment: Are the yellow marked values correct or wrong?

Comment: The yellow marked fields are the fields that the calculation exported and are not matching the "Actual" field which is correct based off of me doing a manual calculation.

Comment: E.g., how do you calculate 7 for 4/15?

Comment: 3/11/17=2: + 3/18/17=1: + 3/25/17=0: + 4/1/17=1: + 4/8/17=1: +  4/15/17=2

Comment: When you include the current row, why is the result for 3/4 1 instead of 2? `ROWS 5 PRECEDING` should work.

Comment: I manually typed in the first two rows instead of using the formula. This was done by mistake.I have corrected this to show all the data that I have included including all weeks. The N/A show because I did a vlookup from the data output from the Query using the Fisc Week Of Month and there are missing weeks for the weeks with 0 inventory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This utilizes EXPAND ON to create the missing rows with a zero quantity, applies the average and finally removes the added rows again:

```
SELECT 
   SID
  ,Begin(pd) AS eow_dt
  -- set the quantity to zero for non-existing weeks
  ,CASE WHEN FISC_EOW_DT = Begin(pd) THEN net_unit_qty ELSE 0 END AS qty
  -- finally calculate the average of the previous 5 plus the current row
  ,Sum(qty) 
   Over (PARTITION BY sid 
         ORDER BY Begin(pd)
         ROWS 5 Preceding) / 6.000 AS avsaleslast6wk
FROM
 (
   SELECT
      SID
     ,FISC_EOW_DT
     ,NET_UNIT_QTY
     ,pd
   FROM
    (
      SELECT 
         SID
        ,FISC_EOW_DT
        ,NET_UNIT_QTY
        -- first: find the next existing row using LEAD
        ,Coalesce(Min(FISC_EOW_DT) 
                  Over (PARTITION BY SID 
                        ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT 
                        ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND 1 Following )
                 ,FISC_EOW_DT+7) AS next_week
      FROM tbl1
    ) AS dt
      -- then: create the missing weeks
   EXPAND ON PERIOD(FISC_EOW_DT, next_week) AS pd BY INTERVAL '7' DAY
 ) AS dt
-- remove the non-existing weeks again
QUALIFY qty > 0
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Edit:

Of course this assumes that there's only a single row per week.

Another solution uses a brute force approach which is ok for a small number of weeks: check if each of the previous 6 rows is within the range of 6 weeks, then add the quantity.

```
SELECT 
   SID
  ,FISC_EOW_DT
  ,net_unit_qty
  ,(CASE WHEN Min(FISC_EOW_DT) 
              Over (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) >= FISC_EOW_DT - 5*7
         THEN Min(net_unit_qty) 
              Over (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding)
        ELSE 0
    END
  + CASE WHEN Min(FISC_EOW_DT) 
              Over (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 2 Preceding AND 2 Preceding) >= FISC_EOW_DT - 5*7
         THEN Min(net_unit_qty) 
              Over (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 2 Preceding AND 2 Preceding)
        ELSE 0
    END
  + CASE WHEN Min(FISC_EOW_DT) 
              Over (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 3 Preceding AND 3 Preceding) >= FISC_EOW_DT - 5*7
         THEN Min(net_unit_qty) 
              Over (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 3 Preceding AND 3 Preceding)
        ELSE 0
    END
  + CASE WHEN Min(FISC_EOW_DT) 
              Over (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 4 Preceding AND 4 Preceding) >= FISC_EOW_DT - 5*7
         THEN Min(net_unit_qty) 
              Over (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 4 Preceding AND 4 Preceding)
        ELSE 0
    END
  + CASE WHEN Min(FISC_EOW_DT) 
              Over (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 5 Preceding AND 5 Preceding) >= FISC_EOW_DT - 5*7
         THEN Min(net_unit_qty) 
              Over (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 5 Preceding AND 5 Preceding)
        ELSE 0
    END
  + net_unit_qty
   ) / 6.000  AS avsaleslast6wk
FROM tbl1
```

This is a lot of cut & paste & modify, but probably quite efficient, a single step.

Comment: I get the following error: Invalid Period Value Constructor.THE BEGINNING BOUND MUST BE LESS THAN THE ENDING BOUND

Comment: @MrLockett: You will get this if there's more than one row with the same value in `FISC_EOW_DT`. Based on your example this should'n exist.

Comment: The second Query seems to have worked. I do have duplicate SID's as they can fall under different channels in the same week. I made a Modification where I am doing 6*6 instead of 6*7 and it will show me the last 6 weeks average for the SKU. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I will test to ensure its working correctly!

Comment: @MrLockett: When you got multiple rows per SID/week you will run into trouble, there might be more than 6 rows for the previous 6 weeks and the average calculation will be wrong, too.

Comment: This will happen with the second table as Query as well?

Comment: @MrLockett: Of course, because it only look at the last 6 rows, if there are other rows in that 6 week range they will be missed. You might pre-aggregate those rows first, then do the calculation and join the result back.

Comment: How would I get the Current row plus the last 5 weeks for a rolling 6 weeks? I am struggling trying to get those numbers to tie out?

Comment: @MrLockett: `ROWS 5 PRECEDING` includes the current row.

Comment: I have put an example in my Question of how it is not tieing out, with the calculation based on the actual amounts. Not sure why this is not tieing out.

Comment: @MrLockett: `ROWS 5 PRECEDING` returns exactly what you want.

Comment: So are you saying use the second query that you posted and only go up to the section where rows 5 is present. I think that is where my confusion is coming from. Thanks for all your help on this.

Comment: @MrLockett: Yes, for the 2nd query remove the 6th row and add the current value instead.

Comment: I have added the code that I believe you are saying that I need to do to my question, but it is still not tieing out, I feel like I am doing something incorrectly.

Comment: @MrLockett: You count the previous week twice and you check for 6 weeks before the current instead of 5. I edited my answer.

Comment: You my friend are a GENIUS!! Thank you so much. This worked Perfectly and tied out correctly. The mistake I was making when I was troubleshooting is that I never + net_unit_qty at the end. I tried 5*7 and removed the 6 row, but never added the units at the end!! Thank you so much. THis makes so much more sense. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your sample data and desired output, I think you are looking for sum of previous 6 weeks divided by `6` and `reset` when there is  gap between weeks, in this case below can be an option.

```
WITH difference (
    sid
    ,FISC_EOW_DT
    ,diff
    )
AS (
    SELECT t1.sid
        ,t1.FISC_EOW_DT
        ,t1.FISC_EOW_DT - Min(t1.FISC_EOW_DT) OVER (
            ORDER BY t1.FISC_EOW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 1 preceding
                    AND 1 preceding
            ) AS diff
    FROM table1 t1
    )
SELECT t.sid
    ,t.FISC_EOW_DT
    ,t.NET_UNIT_QTY
    ,coalesce(cast(SUM(t.NET_UNIT_QTY) OVER (
                ORDER BY t.FISC_EOW_DT RESET WHEN d.diff > 7 ROWS BETWEEN 7 preceding
                        AND 1 preceding
                ) AS DECIMAL(4, 3)) / 6, 0) AS AverageCalc
FROM difference d
INNER JOIN table1 t ON d.sid = t.sid
    AND d.FISC_EOW_DT = t.FISC_EOW_DT;
```

what the query does is that derived table calculate the difference of dates between current and preceding row and in main query, the difference is used as `reset` if its more than `7` determining that weeks are not continuous.

**Result:**

```
SID    FISC_EOW_DT     NET_UNIT_QTY   AverageCalc
----   -----------     ------------   ---------
1234   2017-01-01      1              0.000
1234   2017-01-08      2              0.167
1234   2017-01-15      3              0.500
1234   2017-01-22      2              1.000
1234   2017-01-29      1              1.333
1234   2017-06-09      1              0.000
```

PFB screenshot FYR.

[image]

Comment: Nice idea, but it will fail if there's a gap whit less than 6 weeks, e.g. remove 22-Jan-17, then the next row will show 0 instead of 1.

Comment: @dnoeth:  Yes you are right. By looking into the limited sample data provided, i solve it on the assumptions :-)